# Programming a climbing system like tomb raider

Tags: c++, game-mechanics, level-design, game-design

I was wondering if anyone knew or had knowledge of how to program a climbing system like the one found in tomb raider/uncharted.

I had thought of just having bounding boxes at all the climbable positions in the game world and then check for collision. If the player was inside the box then they would be "hanging" from the edge. Anyone have any better ideas/improvments?

I already have my rendering set up using directx9 and was going to worry about animation later on.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GFu44oeLYPI&feature=relmfu - Some *really* good information.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ledge grab and climb in Unity3D](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10809/ledge-grab-and-climb-in-unity3d)

Comment: @bummzack the question is the same, but the context is entirely different. Interestingly, I hadn't seen that question before, but the best answer has the link I posted haha.

Comment: and if anybody knew where to find a rigged humanoid model, for future reference, we could test our IK code forever and ever.

Comment: http://www.3dbuzz.com/vbforum/sv_videonav.php?fid=3e87b1f570fc9c24ab89ad850ec2f71b I have found a set of tutorial videos for creating a 3rd person character system in Unity. I haven't watched it yet but I'm sure it could be converted to work with other languages as the principle of climbing would be the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Valve's 2009 presentation on the [AI systems behind Left4Dead](https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/apps/valve/2009/ai_systems_of_l4d_mike_booth.pdf) goes into considerable detail on the system used for climbing, including ledge detection, obstacle height, animation selection etc.

It is mostly aimed at NPC animation, but most of the actual climbing code should be very similar.